# Moderators vs. users

Tags: discussion

Who decides and manages the moderators on this site? My experience is that they are rather conceited and condescending to users, preferring lengthy verbal arguments than attempting to provide a few quick possible solutions to honest questions. This only tarnishes the reputation of Ubuntu. The powers that be should be aware of this and heed my critiques...

Comment: As a relatively new user to Ubuntu (but 25+ years experience running my own software house) I too was alarmed at a response by one 'expert' to a question I attempted to answer so I fought back and I think in the end common sense ruled the day. Surely it is better to be a positive (if perhaps in-expert) contributor rather than just always a 'taker' or observer.

Comment: Yes indeed the problem is that that are 'so called experts' as the saying goes one thing you can be sure about is that the so called experts are usually wrong. I think many of these guys are simply here on an ego trip rather than for altruistic purposes this is a shame and only Tarnishes Ubuntuś reputation...

Comment: Care to edit this question with links and examples to illustrate your point?

Comment: "the so called experts are usually wrong" You not understanding what an expert says does not make THEM wrong. Again: EXAMPLES.

Comment: [All of us decide on the moderators, through elections.](http://askubuntu.com/election)

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance the key is to be a *positive* contributor. Inexpert ones often suggest quick fixes that are harmful in the long run.

Comment: Really you have misunderstanding about moderator!

Answer (score 15):

This is about [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503026/cd-drive-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-lts) (10k users can see it still).
It was closed by 5 normal users, and marked for deletion by another high-rep user and me.

I interrupted the argument you were having with another user yesterday on the main site and pointed out that your record of behaviour up to that point was unacceptable. I did this out-of-band (and out out public view) because fights and resulting disciplinary messages (aka "drama") hurt the community.

As I said I would, I have already contacted the other party and they have apologised unreservedly for losing their cool but as I said at the time, the message I sent to you was about your conduct, not theirs.

I don't see that being conceited. You disagree. I can live with that.

---

If you're in a situation where you feel a moderator has been unfair to you, there are still options:

- You can ask for the opinion from another mod (we often do this ourselves if we find ourselves cornered). In this case where a mod-message was sent, all the other mods get a notification about it and could chip in (or contact me in our mod chat room) if they disagreed or had something to add. Neither of those things has happened here.
- You can complain to Stack Exchange directly through the [Contact Us](http://meta.askubuntu.com/contact) link in the footer. They can see everything and could de-moderate us if we did something really bad.
- And because most of the mods are Ubuntu Members, you could complain directly to the  [Community Council](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommunityCouncil)... though I'm not sure what they could do other than rescind our Ubuntu Membership (which has nothing to do with Ask Ubuntu).
- Play the long-con, become a moderator and somehow beat my at my own game.

But more than anything you've clearly ignored the message I sent you. You're already whittering on about fifteen year olds in the comments as if that means something. If you're here to ask for help, ask for it and respond politely when people suggest things.

In direct answer to your question:

- [These are the moderators](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators)
- You can recognise them on the site by the ♦ next to their names.
- [They were elected](https://askubuntu.com/election/) by the users of the site
- Most users can comment and just because they're not moderators (or if they're fifteen) it doesn't mean what they're saying is any less worthwhile. As a *new user* you might want to recognise that.
- Most users can flag things for closure.
- Some users can vote for closure and deletion directly (but it still takes more than one).

Comment: I'll let you handle this since I do not want to end up in lengthy arguments with you >:-D

Comment: In answer to Warren Hill and Rinzwind the whole exchange was deleted from the site, the evidence is gone mate... In answer to muru, 'tell me something i don know', no doubt mr. muru fancies himself as n expert. Look this whole thing was meant to get to the 'powers at be' on ask Ubuntu. Evidently and regrettably this is not what has happened, so nothing will get fixed or improved...

Comment: @debonaire57 [It still exists](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503026/cd-drive-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-lts) and 10k users can see it if they wish. The evidence of what I'm talking about is still very much there. And why the hell are you picking a fight with muru now?

Comment: Forgive my (inexpert) ignorance, but how does one identify a moderator?

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance We have pretty little diamonds next to our names and there's a list of us [on the Users page](http://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: you are right NoviceUserFrance, there is no obvious way. The first idiot i came across was a 15 year old kid who game me the impression (until I looked further) he was a moderator/expert. As i see it it is not obvious who you are delaing with...

Comment: There are no 15 year old idiot moderators on AU.

Comment: @debonaire57 do remember to tag an user using `@`, or they may not get notified. This is the world of computers. Age has little to do with expertise. I know ten-year-olds and 60-year-olds of comparable skill. If you ignore a 15-year-old's advice because he is 15 years old, that is your loss.

Comment: @Rinzwind 'there are no idiot moderators on AU' would be a more precise statement. :)

Comment: @Oli Aha! Thank you. I can see one by your user id now.

Comment: @muru I know I know.

Comment: All these really clever guys here... of which only Novice user france strikes me as a descent and insightful human being, anyway will someone actually answer the question who decides... and will at least some of you heed my advice 'be nice, stop you condescention, etc.act like a human being...' (it  is hard!)

Comment: @debonaire57 We must have had the same 'user experience' at the hands of the same guy then ;) It's nice of you to be so complimentary but I think the answer to your question has already been given (or as much of it as anyone will admit to anyway). The moderators deserve their place and badge of office and can be expected to give quality help. I doubt any of them can be tarred with the same broad brush you are using in the thread about other lesser mortals who sometimes seem to have their own agenda. Other than that, I somehow doubt you will obtain complete satisfaction on this subject.

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance Just to be clear as to why I posted this re-read carefully what I wrote and why... among other things I did not say that there should not be moderators, only that they are quite often flawed and live in dreamw world where they think they a gods... Most of these guys are here on an ego trip not for altruistic purposes... voila mon ami terminé, j'ai essayer d'éveiller la conscience collective pas facile mec...

Comment: @debonaire57 English, please. Your question has been completely answered by Oli's latest edit.

Comment: @debonaire57 Just watch, someone will be along shortly to tell you off for using French! lol   bonne journée et bonne chance! (good day and good luck)

Comment: @muru what did I tell you about being an... what a silly bunch.

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance you were right mate, they even beat you to it, what did I tell you about this sorry lot!

Comment: @debonaire57, NoviceUserFrance, this is an English-only website. What do you expect? O.o

Comment: @oli Like I said you're a condescending, 'holier than thou' = sanctimonious so called moderator, than lives in a dream world

Comment: and this puts an end to this saga, o.k.!

Comment: check on Tim's response and tell me that he has not led me to believe he was a moderator? Fin!!

Comment: @Oli check on Tim's response and tell me that he has not led me to believe he was a moderator? Fin!! –

Comment: @debonaire57 But... now you know how to identify a genuine mod so at least you have learnt something from the exchanges. Win/Win.

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance indeed, one has to learn something new everyday, salut mec (oops, there will be another reaction!!)

Comment: @debonaire57 Ask Ubuntu isn't run by moderators, it's run by the users. We're really here to handle extreme cases and perform mundane tasks to help support the community. We give the users here the abilities to manage the site, and flagging is one of those abilities. As you (and if you) continue using the site [you'll unlock these abilities](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges). We understand this is a pretty stark departure from Forums and other established mediums. I'd like to apologize for any confusion but in review of the actions taken nothing stands out as abusive. Another moderator ->

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Thanks Marco, I never said anything about abusive, only competence, good manners, avoiding condescension, being genuinely altruistic, avoiding egotistical behaviour, and dealing with questions and people intelligently. NovieUserFrance has experienced the same thing I did and possibly from the same person(s)... I don't see myself using this site much, if at all in the future.

Comment: @Debonaire57 Yes, my apologies, I will keep my cool from now on :) Bad day then... I apologies to you personally if I was misleading in anyway or offended you in any way. I am always happy to help, and I realise that I shouldn't have behaved in the way I did. I will do my best to help you if you do have another question, and I will be as polite as I can. I do understand if you don't want to accept my help from now on, my behaviour was unacceptable.

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance Yes, my apologies, I will keep my cool from now on :) Bad day then... I apologies to you personally if I was misleading in anyway or offended you in any way. I am always happy to help, and I realise that I shouldn't have behaved in the way I did. I will do my best to help you if you do have another question, and I will be as polite as I can. I do understand if you don't want to accept my help from now on, my behaviour was unacceptable. –  Tim 2 hours ago. Well, I think I made my point...

Comment: @debonaire57 Is there an election due ;) Good to see you got closure but don't throw the baby out with the bathwater. The site is a useful resource. Never say never!

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance I heed good advice mate <smile> et merci pour le support moral (oops, there we go again another international incident <smile, again>

Comment: @debonaire57 I think it's supposed to be called entente cordiale but but I think they're all out of Vimto right now :)

Comment: @debonaire57 Your mate is at it again...