# Bug in the reputation calculation (possibly involving migration?)

Tags: bug

A user ([Debonaire57](https://askubuntu.com/users/309433/debonaire57?tab=summary)) asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504990/moderators-vs-users) (actually a rant) on Ask Ubuntu. It was swiftly - in 26 minutes - transferred [to Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11648/moderators-vs-users), where it received 14 down votes (actually, 15 and an upvote).

If you look at the user's [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/users/309433/debonaire57?tab=reputation), they have +5 (6) - i.e. 1 upvote on a question - that question. I assume this was before it was transferred - It received a comment from a user that agreed, so I can guess that this was the same, and only, user who upvoted.

For some reason, he didn't get any down votes on the main site, and because all of the down votes are on meta, he kept that plus 5.

Is this a [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug), or [status-bydesign](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), surley all rep gained from a migrated question should migrate to that site?

More worryingly, it may be that it is duplicated, as he kept that upvote on meta. Of course, meta doesn't have rep, but if that was transferred to another rep site (hypothetically, a good question that was moved to, say, Unix & Linux), they may get duplicated rep?

Answer (score 2):

Meta votes and site rep are different.  They measure different things.

Comment: Really? I have 5356 on both sites...

Comment: Meta votes don't affect main rep, and main rep is universal.  Pardon the mis-speaking.  MSO/MSE are different in that respect I think, but generally meta votes measure a different thing and site rep is universal.

Comment: No, I know. But he got a vote before transfer, and kept that, despite transfer and subsequent downvotes.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it could have been downvoted by a mod before migration...  or downvoted by a mod and community before migration (as could have happened with a valid flag).  So, it's not a bug.  Just a ten point fluke, which is not much really.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not much, but his whole rep is 5 points - so it was up voted once, and not down voted until meta?

Comment: Yes.  Bad behavior will land the account in a hurtlocker eventually, or a 5 point bump and a "learn some more" would be equally okay.  You can't give everyone the fire and expect a site to work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm half asleep - hurtlocker? 5 point bump? Fire? O.o

Comment: Think about it and come back later.

Comment: Good idea :) night!